# Haskell indentation - parse error

Tags: haskell

I have a function which looks like this:

```
eval (AppExp e1 e2) env | e2 == [] =
                            case (eval e1 env) of
                                CloVal vv e3 cenv -> eval e3 cenv
                                _  -> ExnVal "Apply to non-closure"
                        | otherwise =
                            case (eval e1 env) of
                              CloVal vv e3 cenv -> let (e:es) = e2
                                                   in case vv of
                                                       [v]  -> eval e3 (H.insert v (eval e env) cenv)
                                                       v:vs -> eval (AppExp (FunExp vs e3) es) (H.insert v (eval e env) cenv
                              _ -> ExnVal "Apply to non-closure"
```

However I get an indentation error on the last line. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Enable `-Wall` and check warnings. (It could be tabs vs spaces)

Comment: Also `case ... of func2 vv ->` is not valid (`func2 vv` is not a pattern)

Comment: func2 is actually a data type

Comment: Show your actual code and the actual error message, please.

Comment: `type` is a keyword and you are using it incorrectly.

Comment: A data type is not a pattern.

Comment: Also, the guard `a == []` is an antipattern. You probably want `func [] b = ... ; func (x:xs) b = ...`. You should use guards only as a last resort, and prefer pattern matching when possible.

Comment: @chi Even if you had to use a guard, `null a` would be better because it doesn't require an `Eq` constraint.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the actual code

Comment: You have an unmatched `(` in `(H.insert`

Comment: Oh! Well thanks for that! My brain just refuses to find those errors. Also where do I put the -Wall argument to check the warnings?

Comment: @Ankush How are you running your code?

Comment: using ghci. I'm not really sure how the code compiles though

Comment: You can either invoke `ghci -Wall` or add at the top of the file `{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}`